# How is the key/label inferred in react native's setState?

Tags: javascript, react-native, syntax, ecmascript-6

I was browsing through the [React Native Autocomplete Input example](https://github.com/l-urence/react-native-autocomplete-input/blob/master/example/Example.android.js) when I came across a classic this.setState call that didn't merge in an object with a label.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      films: [],
      query: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${API}/films/`).then(res => res.json()).then((json) => {
      const { results: films } = json;
      this.setState({ films });
    });
  }
```

I was expecting the this.setState call to look like

```
this.setState({ films: films });
```

Where is the code/documentation that says this syntactic sugar is allowed? Is this a pure javascript feature or a React one?

## Related Research

This feels similar to [object decomposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) but "reversed".

I've also double checked to see that the API call indeed returns an array like

```
"results": [ ... ]
```

so it isn't like `this.setState({ films });` actually has the form `this.setState({ films: actual_object });`.

Comment: It's ES2015 [shorthand property names notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cames from [Object literals shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

```
this.setState({ films });
// is the same as:
this.setState({ films: films });
```

See also http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand for syntactic sugar.